# Why certain line styles do not work in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have following codes:

```
#1
axes[0].plot(x,y, color='blue', ls='>')
#2
axes[0].plot(x,y, color='blue', ls='--')
```

Why code #2 gives me a dashed line, however, #1 does not give triangles?

ls styles can be found here:
https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for 3.3.3, which shows that a `marker` can be a triangle, but `ls` cannot.

Comment: Do you mean `axes[0].plot([0,1],[0,1], '>')`?

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib's plot() function lets you control the linestyle as well as the marker. If you notice, the styles webpage you provided (https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) provides characters for *line styles* and for *markers*.

You can pass these as separate arguments to plot():

```
axes[0].plot(x, y, ls='--', marker='>')
```

Or you can combine them into a single format string:

```
axes[0].plot(x, y, '-->')
```

Or just plot the markers or line on their own:

```
axes[0].plot(x, y, '--') # line only
axes[0].plot(x, y, '>')  # markers only
```

Comment: Perfect answer, in my opinion.